Conditions to Apply Separation of Variables

$$u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta}=0, \qquad 3<r<4$$
$$u(3,\theta)=3\cos(\theta), \qquad -\pi\leq\theta\leq\pi$$
$$u(4,\theta)=4\sin(\theta), \qquad -\pi\leq\theta\leq\pi$$

There are $3$ conditions that must be satisfied to apply separation of variables.
$1$) Rectangular domain - this is obviously satisfied
$2$) Equation is homogenous - this is obviously true
$3$) Homogenous boundary conditions - I believe a boundary conditions for a function $u$ is homogenous if $u = 0$ satisfies it identically. I don't think this is true. Does this mean we can't apply separation of variables since the boundary conditions are not homogenous, or are they actually homogeneous and am I getting confused?

Hint. Try a solution of the form $u(r,\theta)=f(r)\cos(\theta)+g(r)\sin(\theta)$, with the boundary conditions $f(3)=3, g(3)=0, f(4)=0,$ and $g(4)=4.$

@Gonçalo Thank you. I just want to make sure my thinking is correct about why we can or cannot apply separation of variables. The boundary condition is inhomogenous right meaning separation of variables fails?

As shown by Andrei, separation of variables fails if you try a solution of the form $u(r,\theta)=R(r)T(\theta)$. On the other hand, you can use it to construct a solution of the form $u(r,\theta)=\sum_iR_i(r)T_i(\theta)$. The solution suggested in my hint has this form. You can find another example here.

Let's suppose that you can do separation of variables. Then $u(r,\theta)=R(r)T(\theta)$. Plug in the initial conditions. You get $$\frac{u(3,\theta)}{u(4,\theta)}=\frac{3\cos\theta}{4\sin\theta}$$
This is a function of $\theta$. What I expected to get is $$\frac{u(3,\theta)}{u(4,\theta)}=\frac{R(3)T(\theta)}{R(4)T(\theta)}=\frac{R(3)}{R(4)}$$
This is a constant. So obviously separation of variables will not work.

So my thinking is correct that because the boundary conditions are not homogenous that we can't use separation of variables? Shall we use a transformation to transform them into homogenous boundary conditions and then apply separation of variables?

You should try, but the equation might look more complicated.
